# Google Maps empty tiles if not in the Main Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-intent

I'm trying to make application where user has an option to click on button "Find on Map".
If user clicks "Find on Map" button, I would like to start new activity that contains google map.

I did this tutorial and map shows.
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

However this tutorial shows map in the main activity. That is why I made ViewMap activity which is exactly the same as the main activity in the tutorial showed above.
This is how I start ViewMap activity:

```
  findOnMapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // create an Intent to launch the ViewMap Activity
             Intent viewMap = new Intent(ViewCourse.this, ViewMap.class);
             startActivity(viewMap); // start the ViewContact Activity

            }
        });
```

Here is ViewMap.java:

```
    package com.ijankovic.exammanager;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

    public class ViewMap extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_map);


     mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
     mc = mapView.getController();

     String coordinates[] = {"31.567615", "74.360962"};
     double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
     double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

     GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
     (int) (lat * 1E6),
     (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
     mc.setZoom(7);
     mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false; // we are not displaying route information
}
}
```

Here is view_map.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0jHJ3aWhSfOMZ1gjFMGc8xTf7mASBEtQcynZPOQ"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I know my API key works for sure since map displays if I put ViewMap as the main activity.
However if I try to put it in activity that gets called on button clicked, map opens but everything is grey and tiles do not load. There is Google logo in the bottom left corner.

Here is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.ijankovic.exammanager"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.premission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ijankovic.exammanager.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ViewCourse"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ViewMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Problem:**

Is something wrong with my Intent and ViewMap activity call?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I managed to get google maps with this call:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=New+York+NY)); 
    startActivity(i);
```

However this seems to start google maps app. It is not google maps within my app like the tutorial showed.

Comment: Did u set All permissions in manifest file..Like "Internet"  "maps" "location"..

Comment: I have <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.INTERNET" /> under <manifest> tag. And <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> under <application> tag.

Comment: Can you post your manifest file??

Comment: Please post your manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was!

What I had:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.premission.INTERNET" />
```

What it should be:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So I typed premission instead of permission.
I'm surprised that eclipse does not point syntax errors in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 permissions in your manifest file Before the Internet Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And make sure your `API key` is correct

Comment: My API key is 100% correct since map displays if I put ViewMap as a main activity.

Comment: I added ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission but no luck. Map does not show if ViewMap is not main activity.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out what was the problem and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your manifest file.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```

Comment: I believe the problem is having google maps in activity that gets called via Intent. Every tutorial on the internet has google maps in main activity which works for me too. But, I want to display google maps in new activity which gets started when user presses a button.

Comment: I think as you are using Google API v1 so its deprecated now and to get the services of map you need to register your application on google and get the key. Just check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Comment: Thank you, I checked it. However it is working if ViewMap is main activity, so I guess there is no problem with API key.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out what was the problem and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your map activity have you defined the MapController ? 
There may be possibility that you might have missed the MapView or MapController 
You can use the following code in your mapactivity class
to confirm

```
     private MapView mapView;
     private MapController mc;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
     mc = mapView.getController();

     String coordinates[] = {"31.567615", "74.360962"};
     double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
     double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

     GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
     (int) (lat * 1E6),
     (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
     mc.setZoom(7);
     mapView.invalidate();
     }
```

Comment: When I clicked on button "Find on Map" grid seemed to be moving as if it was locating coordinates you provided, but tiles are not displaying. Everything is grey and there is Google logo in the bottom left corner.

Comment: just confirm me 1 thing are you testing it on emulator Like runing directly 
or 
creating an .apk file and then running it on device explicitly ?

Comment: I'm testing it on device but running it from eclipse. So I'm using debug API key.

Comment: your every thing is fine but can`t figured out why it is not showing Using this code and make a sample project and run that if that works fine than you are missing something here in your this project

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out what was the problem and answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Copy and Paste this class in your project.I have tested in my Demo Project and it worked for me...
Hope it will work for you also .. :)

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity
{
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;
    private GeoPoint geoPoint;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_map);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.setZoom(16);

        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(31.567615 * 1E6),(int)(74.360962 * 1E6));
        mc= mapView.getController();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);                       
        mc.animateTo(geoPoint);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out what was the problem and answered my question.